# Django/Wagtail SnippetChooser template

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-admin, wagtail-snippet

[image]1.How i can change/override SnippetChooser template ?

2.How i can add custom filters,queryset manipulations when choosing snippet ?

I can't find any info about this in documentation of wagtail

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: @LucasGrugru I don’t quite understand why you need this. Any example of how this can be implemented will be enough for me

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. https://github.com/neon-jungle/wagtailmodelchooser
2. https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail-generic-chooser

I found these tools.Too bad it is not implemented in in Wagtail...